# Why does xfreerdp say "connected" three times every time?

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, remote-desktop, xfreerdp

Every time I use xfreerdp on Mint 17 to connect to a Windows Server 2003 box, it gives the successful "connected" line identically three times before launching the window:

```
$ xfreerdp (mycommandlineargshere)
connected to (myhostnamehere)
connected to (myhostnamehere)
connected to (myhostnamehere)
```

**Why?**

I tried `strace` once to a file, hitting Ctrl+C between the third `connected to` and before the window actually opened.  Then I tried it again, but quickly hit Ctrl+C after the first `connected to`.  I compared the files, and besides differing memory addresses, they appear identical, with the same number of lines and the exact same file size, down to the byte.  I suppose then that we can conclude the latter two `connected to` statements occur without any `strace` output.

Comment: Can you show an example? Also prefixing it with `strace -s 2000 -o my.log ...` will give you further insights.

Comment: @slm not sure how an example helps, but there it is.  Will try `strace`, thanks

Comment: @slm I'm not willing to post the log because of the detail it contains.  I don't see anything that occurs exactly three times.  What am I looking for?